# Error accesing shared folder in Samba

Tags: samba, solaris

Im using Solaris 10 with Samba 3.6.6. When I tried to access a share folder I get following error.

```
2013/08/27 02:43:38.450317,  4] smbd/reply.c:794(reply_tcon_and_X)
Client requested device type [?????] for share [IPC$]
[2013/08/27 02:43:38.450402,  3] lib/access.c:338(allow_access)
Allowed connection from 10.210.216.87 (10.210.216.87)
[2013/08/27 02:43:38.450619,  3] smbd/service.c:872(make_connection_snum)
Connect path is '/tmp' for service [IPC$]
[2013/08/27 02:43:38.450749,  3] smbd/vfs.c:102(vfs_init_default)
Initialising default vfs hooks
[2013/08/27 02:43:38.450818,  3] smbd/vfs.c:128(vfs_init_custom)
Initialising custom vfs hooks from [/[Default VFS]/]
[2013/08/27 02:43:38.451428,  4] smbd/sec_ctx.c:314(set_sec_ctx)
setting sec ctx (102740793, 100000513) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/08/27 02:43:38.451498,  0] lib/util.c:1117(smb_panic)
PANIC (pid 27019): sys_setgroups failed}
```

I added in the smb.conf the line "ignore syssetgroups error = yes", but testparm returned the error:
    Unknown parameter encountered: "ignore syssetgroups error"
    Ignoring unknown parameter "ignore syssetgroups error"

Do I need to upgrade the Samba version?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just need Solaris release 10 8/11. Add the following line in the /etc/system: set ngroups_max=1024 and reboot. You can refer to the following links:

http://www.nineproductions.com/solaris-10-samba-zfs-configuration/

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/821-2730/gkuhd.html#glapu